# Dragonfire SDK response from PHP

Tags: php, response, dragonfire-sdk

I am trying to program a query of a mysql database with Dragonfire SDK. But as response i got the whole HTML-Structur instead of a single Variable. In this example, i want the last name for the entered first name. Any Ideas?

PHP:

> `<?php`
> `$Fname= $_GET[Fname];`
>
> `$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM Names WHERE Fname = '$Fname'";`
>
> `$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);`
>
> `while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))`
>
> `{`
>
> `echo $row->Lname;`
>
> `}`
> `?>`

C++:

> `int OnResponse(int event, char *response, int length)`
>
> `{`
>
> `response[length]=0;`
>
> ```
>    TextSetText(NameResponse, response);
>
>    return(length);
> ```
>
> `}`

The response looks like this:
`<html>`
`<head>`
`<title>PHP-Test</title>`
`</head>`
`<body>`
`</body>`
`</html>Polo`

But i only want the "Polo"..

Answer (score 0):

Since that PHP is running inside a webpage, its output is going to end up inside a webpage, and NetSend() has no means to separate out the bits of the resulting webpage you want from those you don't. Assuming you can't get your PHP to replace the webpage with some flat text instead of just adding text to it (I don't know enough PHP to suggest anything there), you will need your NetSend() callback to parse the output to find the bit you want. For instance:

```
char *SkipWhiteSpace(char *cp)
{
  while (cp && *cp && cp-response < length && (*cp==' ' || *cp=='\t')) cp++;
  return cp;
}

int OnResponse(int event, char *response, int length)
{
  char *cp = response;

  cp = SkipWhiteSpace(cp);
  while (cp && *cp && cp-response < length && *cp=='<') {
    while (cp && *cp && cp-response < length && *cp!='>') cp++;
    cp++;
    cp = SkipWhiteSpace(cp);
  }
  if (!cp || !*cp || cp-response >= length) return -1;
  // cp now points to the beginning of the desired string
  //...
}
```